# Notepad++ Remove Empty Spaces or characters after the specific LAST character

Tags: character, notepad++, line

Is there any way to tell Notepad please do this...

FROM THIS

```
15.63387,46.42795,1,130,1,210,Sele pri Polskavi
```

TO THIS

```
15.63387,46.42795,1,130,1,210
```

I would like to remove everything after the last , (after number 210)

So that in the end it looks like

```
15.63387,46.42795,1,130,1,210
```

Thing is when I try it using Notepad++ with the command

```
FIND = [[:alpha:]] or [\u\l]
REPLACE = (leave it empty)
```

It removed all alphabetical characters but it leaves , signs at the end, which I can remove with `.{1}$` but for some reason some lines have empty spaces after , sign.

Some lines have one or more and this command `.{1}$` does not work since notepad++ sees empty space as a character and therefore does not remove all the , signs at the end of each line.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239) and explain what are the rules to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `,[^,\r\n]+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately not...since some lines have more than one empty character after that..so still many remains with , sign after that. I am not able to remove all of them with .{1}$ since some have emtpy character after , sign It would be awesome to be able to tell notepad++ please remove everything after THE LAST comma , sign including empty spaces. –

Comment: @HARPER: This is unclear, don't you want to remove spaces at the end of the line?

Comment: Yes I would like...let me paste a part of the txt file..

15.63387,46.42795,1,130,1,210,Sele pri Polskavi


I would like to remove everything after the last ,

So that in the end it looks like

15.63387,46.42795,1,130,1,210

Thing is when I try it using Notepad++ with the command

FIND = [[:alpha:]] or [\u\l]
REPLACE = (leave it empty)

It removed all alphabetical charac but it leaves , signs, which I can remove with .{1}$ but for some reason some lines have empty spaces after...some one or more and this command does not work since notepad++ sees empty space as a character.

Comment: @HARPER: Look at my update, is this what you want?

Comment: No :( It sees 0 results therefore 0 replace options...

Here is the file..maybe you can understand it better

https://pixeldrain.com/u/D3DGkfaK

Comment: @HARPER: Sorry I missed a `+` after the character class! See my edit.

Comment: It worked like a magic. Thank you very much.

This saved me a lot of time and hard work. Amazing.